# Typescript is not warning that a key doesn't exist on type

Tags: typescript

I have the following ts definition:

```
interface FormValue {
  fieldA: string;
  fieldB: number;
}

const FIELD_NAMES: Record<string, keyof FormValue> = {
  FIELD_A: 'fieldA',
  FIELD_B: 'fieldB'
} as const;
```

I want to the to use `FIELD_NAMES.FIELD_A`, this works fine, but this has an issue, when I use something like`FIELD_NAMES.X` typescript is not warning me that `X` does not exist on `FIELD_NAMES`.

How can I solve this?

Here is the full playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=51&pln=6&pc=21#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHsoFsBqcA2ArigN4CwAUMsjMBPgCYCCAXMgM5hSgDmA3JWq16DAEJsQhLACNoAigF9KlBOhCc0ASQCiAGQAiAfQByTALLaAymwBKEVVAYAeTtxA8ANMgDWEAJ7oMGiYuATEAHzIALzI5FRaekasyADkwoxMKR6CCQaG4qnpYimUCshw7Miq6mDyKmoakBoxqDp5phaWAHStiYZM8tWNEJwATNG5Rh1WXQAafMgA9IvIIOjI0FCYyAD8yhRD6PgQXfjoPAAUTWAAlIMNRydnl9ejd0A

Comment: You gave it a type annotation that says any `string` is a valid key. If you remove the type annotation then it will do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Types and [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) don't go together very well. If you remove the type and use the [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to express your constraints, you'll get the behavior you want while still maintaining type safety:

```
interface FormValue {
  fieldA: string;
  fieldB: number;
}

const FIELD_NAMES = {
  FIELD_A: 'fieldA',
  FIELD_B: 'fieldB'
} as const satisfies Record<string, keyof FormValue>;

const test = FIELD_NAMES.FIELD_A;
const test2 = FIELD_NAMES.X;

console.log(test);
console.log(test2);
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHsoFsBqcA2ArigN4CwAUMsjMBPgCYCCAXMgM5hSgDmA3JWq16DAEJsQhLACNoAigF9KlBOhCc0ASQCiAGQAiAfQByTALLaAysgC8yclS16jrZAHJhjJm4A0gpwaG4u6eYm6UCshw7Miq6mAccGDA7MIxAEoQqlAMADyc3CA8PsgA1hAAnugwaJi4BMQAfPIqahqQGnaoOoGmFpYAdN3Ohkzyce0QnABMtgFGfVYDABotFBPo+BAD+Og8ABQdYACU422b27sHR9OnQA)</sup>